# Is the a way to disable interrupt sepcial core's interruput on x86(in linux userspace)

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, multicore

Now, I have a piece of code when it run, I don't want it be interrupted. So I want to know is
there a way to disable it or don't handle any interrput.

And is there a way let sepcial core only run one process.

Answer (score 0):

To disable interrupts you can implement a system call that would call

```
irq_disable()
```

and

```
irq_enable()
```

when you are exiting. However disabling interrupt should in most cases be done for very quick operations. You could also need to be root to execute that syscall (to be checked).

For your second question, if I understood it well, you can set process affinities via

```
   int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize,cpu_set_t *mask);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention specifically that this is a user space application, you may want to look into using one of the many synchronization primitives provided by linux. The one you choose to use will depend on what you are trying to do. This will let you define a critical section of your code without the potential for race conditions and or deadlocks.